# How to switch from LayoutInflater to AsyncLayoutInflater in a Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I am using a Dialog Fragment in a project, but a client wanted to have the background behind the Dialog Fragment blurred when the fragment is active. I used the library BlurKit that adds that translucency effect from iOS, but although it doesn't lag my application at all, the Dialog Fragment layout inflation is a little bit slower now to admit. Basically, the fast blur appliance happens on the Main Activity, then immediately the Dialog Fragment gets shown, but with a delay of about 0.8 seconds. If disabling that blur effect Fragment gets shown almost instantly.

I've searched online for a solution and I found out about AsyncLayoutInflater that is relatively faster. How can I convert my code for this async inflater to see if this solves the short delay with the blur on.

```
public class ExpenseDialogFragment extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment_expense, container, false);
        getViewReferences(view);
        setCancelable(false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = Objects.requireNonNull(
                Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog()).getWindow()).getAttributes();
        layoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        layoutParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        Objects.requireNonNull(getDialog().getWindow()).setAttributes(layoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //stuff here
    }
```

Comment: The usage of AsyncLayoutInflater is briefly explained here in its documentation itself.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater

Comment: Hi! Don't know if you solve it, I recently have a similar requeriment and this is how I solve it, using `AsyncLayoutInflater`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035412/2597775